# How to share screenshot of libgdx game score in whatsapp and facebook?

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx

I am developing a game using **libgdx** for android and **ios**.
I have already obtained screenshot using this function,

```
public void take() {
    byte[] pixels = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);

    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    BufferUtils.copy(pixels, 0, pixmap.getPixels(), pixels.length);
    PixmapIO.writePNG(Gdx.files.external("mypixmap.png"), pixmap);
    pixmap.dispose();
}
```

How can i share obtained screenshot in *facebook* and *whatsapp*?

Answer (score 1):

Get the path of your ScreenShot and send it like below

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.setType("image/*");
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share image File"));
```

**Note**: Whatsapp dont receive image and text both together.

Comment: Thank You.I think this code is specific for android. I need a code for libgdx(platform independent) that is working in both android and ios.

Comment: That is not possible. Android and iOS are handling intents differently. You have to implement something like an [Interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536189/google-sign-in-with-libgdx/39540760#39540760).