# Is it possible to integrate Google Play Games Services Realtime Multiplayer into LibGDX for both Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have integrated real-time multiplayer in LibGDX for Android. Now I am wondering how to implement it also for iOS. I have a few questions:

Is this possible?

Can Android and iOS players play together?

What are the possible ways to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, of course. Have a look at [interfacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536189/google-sign-in-with-libgdx/39540760#39540760). For the iOS app I would use the [Multi-OS engine](https://multi-os-engine.org/). Use the normal gdx-setup jar file to create moe module.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Currently I am using the old RoboVM for my iOS project. Would it be wise / difficult to switch to Multi-OS engine considering I have a time limit of three weeks?

Comment: I've never worked with RoboVM, but MOE is not very difficult to understand.

Comment: Thank you. I do understand how interfaces work, but so far I only found Java code for realtime multiplayer for Android, and Objective C code for iOS. Do you know where to find Java code for iOS?

Comment: As you figured out, iOS uses Objective C / Swift. MOE gives you the possibility wo wrap those frameworks / libraries into a jar and creates Java bindings. It is called [Nat/J Binding Generator](https://doc.multi-os-engine.org/multi-os-engine/6_natj/natjgen_binding_generator/NatJGen_Binding_Generator.html).